# How to identify a span and add to it's classlist

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have code that creates spans, and my goal is to change the color of a few of those spans based on the text they contain. I have inserted a comment where I have a question about the syntax of the code I should write in there. I am looking to find the span based on it's text, and add is-active to it's `classList`.

```html
    <head>
        <style>
            .tagger1010 span 
            {
    padding: 6px 10px;
    background: #D0E8E4;
    border-radius: 18px;
    color: #000000;
    font-family: Roboto;
    font-size: 12px;
    margin: 0 4px 8px 0;
    font-weight: 500;
    display: inline-block;
    word-wrap: break-word;
    white-space: normal;
              cursor: pointer;
            user-select: none;
border: 1px solid BBD0CD;

            }
    
            .tagger1010 span.is-active {
                background-color: #008fde;
                color: #ffffff;

            }
            
            .tagger1010 span:hover {
                background-color: #008fde;
                color: #ffffff;
            }
        </style>

<body>
    
<div class="tagger1010">
  <span>Google</span>
  <span>Microsoft</span>
  <span>Facebook</span>
  <span>LinkedIn</span>
</div>

<div class="as-console-wrapper"></div>
<div class="as-console"></div>  
 <script type="text/javascript">
       const changeColor = (evt) => {
  if (evt.currentTarget.classList.contains("is-active")) {
    evt.currentTarget.classList.remove("is-active");
  } else {
    evt.currentTarget.classList.add("is-active");
  }
};
const EL_tagger1010_children = document.querySelectorAll(".tagger1010 span");
EL_tagger1010_children.forEach(EL => EL.addEventListener("click", changeColor));

var tags = ["Microsoft","Facebook"];
var spans = div.getElementsByTagName("span");

for(i=0;i<tags.length;i++)
{
  if(spans.includes(tags[i])){
  //Find the span whose text is tags[i], and add is-active to it's classList 
 }
 }
    </script>
    
    <div class="as-console-wrapper">
    <div class="as-console">
    
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your code generates error *div is not defined* in `div.getElementsByTagName("span");`....

Comment: @Mamun Even here? https://onecompiler.com/html/3wpg6gx7d

Comment: It should be "document" not "div"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume `div.getElementsByTagName("span");` would be `document.getElementsByTagName("span");` then you can try using `filter()` like the following:

```
var s = [...spans].filter(j => j.textContent == tags[i])[0];
if(s){
  s.classList.add('is-active')
}
```

**Demo:**

```css
.tagger1010 span {
  padding: 6px 10px;
  background: #D0E8E4;
  border-radius: 18px;
  color: #000000;
  font-family: Roboto;
  font-size: 12px;
  margin: 0 4px 8px 0;
  font-weight: 500;
  display: inline-block;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  white-space: normal;
  cursor: pointer;
  user-select: none;
  border: 1px solid BBD0CD;
}

.tagger1010 span.is-active {
  background-color: #008fde;
  color: #ffffff;
}

.tagger1010 span:hover {
  background-color: #008fde;
  color: #ffffff;
}
```

```html
    
<div class="tagger1010">
  <span>Google</span>
  <span>Microsoft</span>
  <span>Facebook</span>
  <span>LinkedIn</span>
</div>

<div class="as-console-wrapper"></div>
<div class="as-console"></div>  
  <script type="text/javascript">
    const changeColor = (evt) => {
      if (evt.currentTarget.classList.contains("is-active")) {
        evt.currentTarget.classList.remove("is-active");
      } else {
        evt.currentTarget.classList.add("is-active");
      }
    };
    const EL_tagger1010_children = document.querySelectorAll(".tagger1010 span");
    EL_tagger1010_children.forEach(EL => EL.addEventListener("click", changeColor));

    var tags = ["Microsoft","Facebook"];
    var spans = document.getElementsByTagName("span");

    for(i=0;i<tags.length;i++)
    {
      var s = [...spans].filter(j => j.textContent == tags[i])[0];
        if(s){
        //Find the span whose text is tags[i], and add is-active to it's classList
        s.classList.add('is-active')
      }
    }
  </script>
    
  <div class="as-console-wrapper">
  <div class="as-console">
    
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably don't want to simply check if the spans include the tag, since you'll want to know which span matched it. You could use a nested for loop:

```
for (i = 0; i < tags.length; i++) {
    for (j = 0; j < spans.length; j++) {
        if (spans[j].textContent === tags[i]) {
            spans[j].classList.add('is-active');
        }
    }
}
```

If you want to be a little less verbose:

```
for (var tag of tags) {
    for (var span of spans) {
        if (span.textContent === tag) {
            span.classList.add('is-active');
        }
    }
}
```